# How do I check if input is equal to a lettter in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, input

I am creating a hangman game and I was wondering how I would check if an inputted letter is equal to one in the array. The code is below.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = 0;
System.out.println("Enter a word for hangman!!");
String word = input.next();

char[] word2 = word.toCharArray();

do{
    System.out.println("guess a letter");
    String letter = input.next();
    if(letter.  ){

    }

}while( x < 5 );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a simple method

```
boolean containsLetter(char letter)
{
    for(Char c : word2)
    {
        if(c == letter)
            return true;
    }
    // We got here means no matches
    return false;
}
```

Then check:

```
if(!containsLetter(letter))
    // does not contain the letter
```

Comment: Thanks so much sorry if this was a dumb question but im pretty new but thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunatly i cant /: requires 15 rep